# ¿Como cambio grosor de linea en canvas segun un intervalo?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Deseo crear un elemento en canvas que cambie el grosor del borde cada 3 segundos,
que tenga un grosor de linea 5px iniciando, 3 segundos despues tenga otro grosor de 10px, luego de 3 segundos inicie de nuevo en grosor 5px. Es decir, que este en un loop infinito en cambio de grosor de border. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
      var ctx=c.getContext("2d");

      ctx.strokeStyle="red";
      ctx.lineWidth=5;
      ctx.strokeRect(20,20,100,100);

      setTimeout(function() {
          ctx.clearRect(20,20,100,100);
          //ctx.strokeStyle="black";
          ctx.lineWidth=10;
          ctx.strokeRect(20,20,100,100);
      }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar `setInterval` para ejecutar la función cada 3 segundos y utilizar un flag externo para establecer con qué ancho se debe dibujar:

```js
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
      var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
      ctx.strokeStyle="red";

      var flag = true;
      function dibujar() {
          ctx.clearRect(20,20,100,100);
          ctx.lineWidth=  flag ? 5 : 10;
          flag = !flag;
          ctx.strokeRect(20,20,100,100);
      }
      // Dibujo inicial
      dibujar();
      // Repetir cada 3 s
      setInterval(dibujar, 3000);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: Excelente!! Me parece muy bien, el único detalle es que inicia en blanco el DOM, después de 3 segundos inicia con width 5

Comment: No tienes más que ejecutar la función antes de establecer el `setInterval`. Modifico la respuesta para mostrarlo.

Comment: Excelente! Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda!!